# Pronunciation of ‘deduce’ as duh-DOOS

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, vowels

When I look up some dictionaries, the pronunciation of the word 'deduce' is /dɪˈduːs/, but it is pronounced as **duh·doos** ([dəˈduːs]). Is there a rule when to pronounce the vowel /ɪ/ like that?

Comment: I say it like did use but I am British. There are various ways of saying it.

Comment: "duh deuce" here in Canada

Comment: I'm Canadian and say /dɪˈdjuːs/, so go figure. These differences are effectively regional or personal variations in pronunciation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dictionaries use [phonemic transcriptions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/290208/106592) i.e. only contrastive sounds, not how native speakers actually speak. The word *deduce* is pronounced differently in both British and American English:

- American: /dɪˈduːs/ (di-DOOS)
- British: /dɪˈdjuːs/ (di-DYOOS)

The first syllable of *deduce* is unstressed whereas the second one is stressed (i.e. the strongest syllable). It's very common in spoken English to reduce unstressed /ɪ/ to a schwa sound (in certain words). The IPA symbol for schwa is **ə** (the sound at the end of *commA*). That's why most speakers pronounce it duh-DOOS/ duh-DYOOS. (In most British accents, you'll also hear the second syllable pronounced with a 'J' sound because of [assimilation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/246248/106592).)

You will also hear *behind, behave, behaviour* etc., pronounced with [bə-] (read [this answer on Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/38419/28073)).

Comment: That's a **very** important fact for any English learner to understand. Most English speakers reduce most of their unstressed vowels to some central vowel, usually represented as schwa /ə/. They may think they're pronouncing something else (usually a letter) but in fact it's schwa. Don't believe what native speakers tell you about pronunciation. They never learned it in school.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's decidedly an AmE phenomenon (the schwa-ification of vowels), not English in general.

Comment: @J... I don't quite agree. There are accents that don't reduce vowels as much, but most UK accents do it as much as American accents.

Comment: Technically, even /ɪ/ is usually reduction of closer and/or more front vowels like /e/, /ɛ/, or /i/.

Comment: @trlkly I mean specifically reduction to schwa (ie: the total elimination of enunciation, not just a softer enunciation)

Comment: @J... Happens here in Australian English. For instance, I've looked at texts that use /ɨ/ for certain reduced vowels and thought, "Nah, I can't discern any difference between that and /ə/." (Incidentally, Wikipedia ascribes /ɨ/ to *American* English!) Anyway, I think you might be overlooking John's point. Reduced vowels being collectively represented as /ə/ is probably a **broad** transcription. A narrow transcription could be more precise, but it's not essential.

Comment: You seem to be saying that the word is commonly pronounced as "duh-DOOS" in American English, rather than "dee-DOOS". As a native speaker of American English who has listened to *many* different speakers of American English from all across the country, I can legitimately say that I've never heard the former "duh" pronunciation, nor have I ever been tempted to use it. I'm therefore very skeptical of this claim.

Comment: @CodyGray AmE accents vary quite a bit. "duh-DOOS" you'll hear generally in accents that have other schwas, like reducing "the" /ði/ to /ðə/.  (Think Kansas, etc).

Comment: What you see in British English is not the reduction of /ɪ/ to /ə/. It's variation between /ɪ/ and /ə/. The latter is not an allophone of the former.